# How to get the list of methods available in the current context in Python

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby `self` is the current context:

```
irb(main):050:0> self
=> main
irb(main):051:0> self.class
=> Object
irb(main):052:0> Object.class
=> Class
irb(main):053:0> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
irb(main):054:0> Object.methods
=> [:new, :allocate, :superclass ... ]
irb(main):055:0> Kernel.methods
=> [:`, :gets, :proc, :lambda, :sprintf ... ]
```

Searching for the `rand` method:

```
irb(main):003:0> (Kernel.methods-Object.methods).grep /rand/
=> [:rand, :srand]
irb(main):004:0> Kernel.methods.count
=> 158
irb(main):006:0> (Kernel.methods-Object.methods).count
=> 60
```

I can easily find out where each method is defined. Here `rand` is defined in the `Kernel` module.

According to the wiki:

> The `Kernel` module is included by `class` Object, so its methods are
>   available in every Ruby object.

Looking at the following Python code:

```
>>> str = 'Hello World'
>>> len(str)
11
```

where is the `len()` function coming from? What object is it called on? How do I get the list of methods available in the current context? And what is the current context in Python similar to `self` in Ruby?

I'm new to Python and find it hard figuring out where to begin.

Comment: Have you gone through some tutorials? Python isn't that hard and the tutorials will help reveal all.

Comment: I have a very short deadline to learn Django and python. So no time for tutorials. Anyway as @Ezer answered dir() was what I was looking for.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261598/128421 will help you understand the SO way. Asking instead of researching will waste time as the process of researching will familiarize you with the Python documentation and you'll learn more and more as you read versus asking every time you want to know one thing.

Comment: You can also check all built-in functions with `vars(__builtins__)`

Comment: @theTinMan With all due respect for your knowledge and seniority, I would like to tell you if one word (dir() in this case) is the expected answer, just answer it. With that answer I was able to completely understand where everything is.

Comment: Yes @TitoOrt I found `_builtins_` when I ran `dir()` on my prompt. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO @vishnuprasanth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the current context methods, but you can retrieve all the available methods and attributes of specific objects using `dir` function.
For example,

```py
from pprint import pprint
my_string = "Hello"
pprint(dir(my_string))
```

```
OUT[1]: 
['capitalize',
 'casefold',
 'center',
 'count',
 'encode',
 'endswith',
 ...]
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: Then I advice you to use pprint, instead of print. since it will show all the methods and attributes line by line. I will edit my answer using it

Comment: Just found out `dir()` without any arguments will give the current context (the list of imported modules and builtins).